# MetaMurderMystery

Tags: riddle, cipher, steganography, imgur-maze

Oh no. Another murder. More work for you, the famous Dr. M. Helos, in the summer, no less.

The story:

A man by the name of Nat Sow was found dead on a bench. When the police found him, they were unable to move him, as if he was a stone stuck to the seat. They uprooted the whole bench, and on closer examination, found these words imprinted into his skin

> kartisanship
>
> vowzhwwpaeq

Can you find who murdered Mr. Sow?

Comment: The first step involves viewing the source - faux-HTML tags lead you to http://i.stack.imgur.com/yCRns.png .

Comment: (Posted as a comment because viewing the source and character-by-character hints are overused, under-fun mechanics IMO. I don't plan to continue.)

Comment: I'm having a really rough time differentiating which (parts of) lines indicate which character position for the link referred to in the image.

Comment: each line is a character, and theyre in order

Answer (score 1):

Op came and leaked the answers to the youtube riddle. I figured there might be someone out there who wants an explanation for the rest of the puzzle. The updated info is at the bottom.

Who killed Nat Sow?

> bleh, aka op

Answers to the riddles found in: i.stack.imgur.com/yCRns.png (linked by Deusovi).

One of five hundred

> 500 == D in roman numerals

Right below number one

> == E, take the first letter (D) and go down one.

what sees, what is oneself

> i (eye, me)

the gaping hole, the void

> o

??? A letter that was missing because OP is dumb

> r

whose uppercase version is lower than itself

> dash - if you uppercase on a keyboard (SHIFT) it's underscore _

the number that is neither good or bad

> 0

the one that is 137 and 89, the twin of another

> (89)<sub>16</sub> = (137)<sub>10</sub>, and in the [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) encoding schema, those are the codes for i (don't know what I was doing, meant to use ascii)

the latter of the middle brothers

> m,n -> n

the one that is 9 after me, but 11 before

> play on words of IX being 9 and XI being 11

and finally, the first part of the link

> you-tube == u

And we get

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEior-0inxU Vermeer? Wait, what's that painting on OP's profile pic called? (Girl with a Pearl Earring - Johannes Vermeer)

So now we take a look at the words imprinted into the man's skin:
kartisanship and vowzhwwpaeq

kartisanship

> is an anagram for thisisaprank. This is our key for a Vigenère cipher. Plug in vowzhwwpaeq, and you get OVERPOWEREDF (probably not supposed to have an F).

These two clues combined:

> OVERPOWERED has an abbreviation of OP, and Vermeer painted OP's picture, leading us to believe it is bleh who killed Nat Sow. As bleh stated before, the final answer was leaked in chat a while ago. I'm just updating this so those who don't check it can see.

Comment: ...But 500 is D in Roman numerals not C.

Comment: @Sid Silly op. I'll go ahead and fix it :)